# Ruby skips a section of script

Tags: ruby, heap, infinite-loop, greedy

Ruby noob here, and I am having an infuriating issue.

Something in my script is making Ruby skip a section of it.

```
#Main_block_begins_here
if __FILE__ == $0
  #Open_the_file_with_values_and_weights                    
  File.open(getFileName, 'r') do |f|
    #Intial_data...
    $totalNumber=f.gets.chomp!.to_i
    $totalCapacity=f.gets.chomp!.to_i
    $currentItemWeight=0
    $currentItemValue=0
    $spaceLeft=0
    $spaceLeft=$totalCapacity
    $takenWeight=0
    $takenValue=0

    #Make_a_heap_for_the_data
    $prioQ = Heap.new do
      #reads_values,_computes_them,_and_enqueues_them                    
      until i==$totalNumber
        total=0
        value=f.gets.chomp!.to_i
        weight=f.gets.chomp!.to_i
        total=value/weight
        puts "#{total}=t, #{value}=v, #{weight}=w. Correct?"
        check=gets.chomp!
        it=Obj.new(total, value, weight) do
          prioQ.enqueue(it)
        end
        i+=1
      end 
    end

    #dequeueIt

    puts "total weight taken was #{$takenWeight} and total value taken was #{$takenValue}."
  end
end
```

The commented line #dequeueIt is a method earlier on that when I let run, it gives me an infinite loop with all values that were supposed to be read in from the text file as zeros.

The puts line and the check declaration line inside the until loop are for debugging purposes, and of course they never print out.

Commented out, when I run the program it just prints out the last line as if the until loop never ran. If more code for context is necessary, just let me know and I'll put it up.

My hair's starting to fall out over this one, so any help is appreciated!

EDIT:: Yes, it should have been i==$totalnumber. I fixed it in my code and it still doesn't execute the script inside that loop.

Comment: `i=$totalNumber` – shouldn’t that be `==`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Still doesn't fix the problem though...

Comment: You almost certainly don't want your variables to begin with `$`. `$` makes the variables global variables, which will eventually make you sad. E.g., `totalNumber` rather than `$totalNumber`.

Comment: Well I had needed to access those variables from the dequeueIt method. Is there a better way to make that possible besides globalizing it?

Comment: Where is `i` first defined now? Your code as currently shown will give an error (`undefined local variable or method \`i'`).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That's really strange, though. I did forget to initialize that variable, but when I run the script it doesn't return any errors...

Comment: That's because global variables, like eg. instance variables, are implicitly initialized with _nil_. (Try to type `$prick` vs. just `prick` in your `irb` session.)

Answer (score 1):

This is one oversight:

```
until i=$totalNumber
```

This assigns a number to i; it is always true. Try

```
until i==$totalNumber
```